# Add an index (or counter) to a dataframe by group in R

Tags: r, indexing, counter, plyr, seq

I have a df like

```
ProjectID Dist
  1        x
  1        y
  2        z
  2        x
  2        h
  3        k
  ....     ....
```

I want to add a third column such that we have an incrementing counter for each ProjectID:

```
ProjectID Dist counter
  1        x     1
  1        y     2
  2        z     1
  2        x     2
  2        h     3
  1        k     3
  ....     ....
```

I've had a look at `seq` `rank` and a couple of other bits particularly looking to see if I could use `ddply` to help:

```
df$counter <- ddply(df,.(projectID), function(x).....? )
```

I think I could adapt this answer [How to create a counter/numeration by group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604568/how-to-create-a-counter-numeration-by-group-in-r) but would prefer something using something like ddply (I can't find an equivalent of cumsum but I think that's the same principle here: [Create ascending series of integers by group in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005925/create-ascending-series-of-integers-by-group-in-pandas) ).  That'd let me index occurrences in a list (and e.g. merge on this).

Comment: You could try `ave` i.e. `df$counter <- with(df, ave(seq_along(ProjectID), ProjectID, FUN=seq_along))` or a compact wrapper would be `library(splitstackshape);getanID(df, 'ProjectID')[]` or using `plyr`; `ddply(df, .(ProjectID), mutate, counter=seq_along(Dist))`

Comment: Ok that works (thank you!) but I don't really understand what it's doing? (my head hurts)

Comment: We are grouping by `ProjectID` and creating a new column as the sequence of `Dist` per each group.  You will find it easy after you read the help pages and try some examples

Comment: It's the use of `ave` I (think) I'm finding confusing - I get the `ddply` example (which also works perfectly, thanks again) but the use of `ave` alongside `seq_along` I'm struggling to get my head around

Comment: In the `ave`,  second argument is the grouping variable i.e. ` ave(x, ..., FUN = mean)`  If you look at the description   ` ...: Grouping variables, typically factors, all of the same
          ‘length’ as ‘x’.`

.   You can also use `ave(ProjectID, ProjectID, FUN=seq_along)`, but when you have `character/factor` columns, this will either result in error or get character elements as output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution is quite simple:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(ProjectID) %>% mutate(counter = row_number(ProjectID))


#  ProjectID Dist counter
#1         1    x       1
#2         1    y       2
#3         2    z       1
#4         2    x       2
#5         2    h       3
#6         1    k       3
```

Comment: `mutate(counter=row_number())` should do it.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question...what's `%>%` do? (And slightly tangential, is there a way to effectively search [google] for that type of code?)

Comment: `%>%` is a pipe or chain operator... it works like this:  `mydata %>% do_something_with_it %>% do_something_else`  - it simply enables you to chain together functions.