# How do I create occasion variable (time) for each ID?

Tags: r, variables

I would like to create variable "Time" which basically indicates the number of times variable ID showed up within each day minus 1. In other words, the count is lagged by 1 and the first time ID showed up in a day should be left blank. Second time the same ID shows up on a given day should be 1.

Basically, I want to create the "Time" variable in the example below.

```
ID Day Time Value
1  1        0
1  1    1   0
1  1    2   0
1  2        0
1  2    1   0
1  2    2   0
1  2    3   1
2  1        0
2  1    1   0
2  1    2   0
```

Below is the code I am working on. Have not been successful with it.

```
data$time<-data.frame(data$ID,count=ave(data$ID==data$ID, data$Day, FUN=cumsum))
```

Comment: check out 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647954/add-an-index-or-counter-to-a-dataframe-by-group-in-r

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', 'Day', we get the `lag` of sequence of rows (`shift(seq_len(.N))`) and assign (`:=`) it as "Time" column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Time := shift(seq_len(.N)), .(ID, Day)]
df1
#    ID Day Value Time
# 1:  1   1     0   NA
# 2:  1   1     0    1
# 3:  1   1     0    2
# 4:  1   2     0   NA
# 5:  1   2     0    1
# 6:  1   2     0    2
# 7:  1   2     1    3
# 8:  2   1     0   NA
# 9:  2   1     0    1
#10:  2   1     0    2
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
with(df1, ave(Day, Day, ID, FUN= function(x)
        ifelse(seq_along(x)!=1, seq_along(x)-1, NA)))
#[1] NA  1  2 NA  1  2  3 NA  1  2
```

Or without the `ifelse`

```
with(df1, ave(Day, Day, ID, FUN= function(x) 
            NA^(seq_along(x)==1)*(seq_along(x)-1)))
#[1] NA  1  2 NA  1  2  3 NA  1  2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Value = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("ID", "Day", 
"Value"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```